# How to create an object factory method for gson method?

Tags: java, gson

I am generating a Student object from a JSON object but problem is when I create this object I also want to update its "studentClass" field. I update setStudentClass() method but I think GSON doesn't use this setter fields. How can I create a factory method for fromJson() method?

```
Student student = gson.fromJson(studentJSON.toString(), Student.class);
student.updateClassInfo();


public class Student{

   private String name;
   private String studentClass;

   //getters and setters

   public void updateClassInfo(){

      if(studentClass.equals("1"))
        studentClass = "starter";
      else if
      .....
   }

}
```

Comment: After converting to POJO, you can set the value of the studentClass attribute. After that what you wanted to achieve? You have the latest values in the Student object.

Comment: Please ensure the field names are exactly the same in JSON string and in POJO. GSON doesn't itself ignore any field. and please add the complete Student class and if possible JSON string as well.

Comment: @notionquest I dont want to call updateClassInfo() method after every time I create a student object. So I thought I can create an object factory method and I can create student objects with this method but gson creates objects a little different I think.

Comment: @UmaisGillani There is no problem with fromJson() method. It works perfect but I want to call updateClassInfo() method everytime I create a new Student object from json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requirement can be fulfilled using custom deserializer. Sample code below:-

**Main method:-**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"John\",\"studentClass\":\"1\"}";
        //String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"John\"}";

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Student.class, new StudentModelDeserializer())
                .create();

        Student student = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Student.class);
        System.out.println(student.toString());

    }
```

**Deserializer:-**

```
public class StudentModelDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Student> {

    @Override
    public Student deserialize(JsonElement paramJsonElement, Type paramType,
            JsonDeserializationContext paramJsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {

        String studentClass = null;
        if (paramJsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("studentClass") != null) {
            studentClass = paramJsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("studentClass").getAsString();
        }

        Student student = new Gson().fromJson(paramJsonElement.getAsJsonObject(), Student.class);

        if (studentClass != null) {
            if (studentClass.equals("1")) {
                student.setStudentClass("starter");
            }
        }

        return student;
    }

}
```

**Output:-**

```
Student [name=John, studentClass=starter]
```

**Output if student class is not present:-**

```
Student [name=John, studentClass=null]
```